# How to replace the IDs with their corresponding values in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I working on 4 tables, 1 main table and 3 small tables. The main table is called 'document' and it is referencing and ID from each of the other 3 small tables which are: importance, nature, access_level.

```
e.g.

(Table1) document

document_id | title | file_name | importance_id | nature_id | access_level_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1     | Food  | food.docx |       1       |     1     |       1        


(Table2) importance

importance_id | name
--------------------
       1      | High


(Table3) nature

nature_id | name
----------------
     1    | General


(Table4) nature

access_level_id | name
----------------------
        1       | Public
```

What I wanted to do is showing all the documents (using SELECT) with their IDs replaced by their corresponding names.. like this:

```
document_id | title | file_name | importance |  nature  | access_level
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1     | Food  | food.docx |    High    |  General |    Public
```

I tried to use this query but it didn't work quite well:

```
SELECT `document_id`, `title`, `file_name`, `date_of_archiving`, `duration_of_life`, importance.name as importance, nature.name as nature, access_level.name as access_level
FROM document, importance, nature, access_level
WHERE importance.importance_id = document.document_id
AND nature.nature_id = document.nature_id
AND access_level.access_level_id = document.access_level_id;
```

SO how can I make that happen?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It looks like your problem is here `importance.importance_id = document.document_id`... this is one of the many reasons that `JOIN` syntax is superior.

Comment: @Uueerdo Yes, the WHERE command eliminates some rows for some reason. The problem is I don't know how to write a proper JOIN syntax and I'd be grateful if you showed me how :)

Comment: Is this with MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server? You've tagged both.

Answer (score 0):

Use JOINS rather than outdated syntax you are using. It is clearer and easier to debug. And to save typing use table aliases. As follows:

```
SELECT 
  document_id, 
  title, 
  file_name, 
  date_of_archiving, 
  duration_of_life, 
  i.NAME AS [importance],
  n.name as [nature], 
  al.name as [access_level]
FROM 
  DOCUMENT D
  JOIN importance i ON i.Importance_id = D.importance_id
  JOIN nature n ON n.nature_id = D.nature_id
  JOIN access_level al on al.access_level_id = D.access_level_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join if you want the rows return no null values

```
SELECT 
  document_id, 
  title, 
  file_name, 
  date_of_archiving, 
  duration_of_life, 
  i.NAME AS [importance],
  n.name as [nature], 
  al.name as [access_level]
FROM 
  DOCUMENT D
  INNER JOIN importance i ON i.Importance_id = D.importance_id
  INNER JOIN nature n ON n.nature_id = D.nature_id
  INNER JOIN access_level al on al.access_level_id = D.access_level_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code:

```
SELECT
  Document_id,
  Title,
  File_name,
  i.name AS Importance,
  n.name AS Nature,
  s.name AS Access_level
FROM Document d
INNER JOIN importance i ON i.importance_id = d.importance_id
INNER JOIN nature n     ON n.nature_id = d.nature_id
INNER JOIN nature s     ON s.access_level_id = d.access_level_id
```